# Python: single colon vs double colon

Tags: python, numpy, slice

What is the difference between single and double colon in this situation?
 `data[0:,4]` vs `data[0::,4]`

```
women_only_stats = data[0::,4] == "female" 

men_only_stats = data[0::,4] != "female"
```

I tried to replace `data[0::,4]` with `data[0:,4]` and I see no difference. Is there any difference in this or another case?

`data` is 2-dimensional array with rows like `['1' '0' '3' 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris' 'male' '22' '1' '0' 'A/5 21171' '7.25' '' 'S']`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No**, there is no difference.

See the Python documentation for [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice):

From the docs: `a[start:stop:step]`

> The start and step arguments default to None. Slice objects have
>   read-only data attributes start, stop and step which merely return the
>   argument values (or their default).

In this case, you are including an empty `step` parameter.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a[2:]
[3,4]
>>> a[2::]
[3,4]
>>> a[2:] == a[2::]
True
```

And to understand what the `step` parameter actually does:

```
>>> b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> b[0::5]
[1, 6]
>>> b[1::5]
[2, 7]
```

So by leaving it to be implicitly `None` (i.e., by either `a[2:]` or `a[2::]`), you are not going to change the output of your code in any way.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Both syntaxes result in the same indexes.

```
class Foo(object):
  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    print(idx)

Foo()[1::,6]
# prints (slice(1, None, None), 6)
Foo()[1:,6]
# prints (slice(1, None, None), 6)
```

Basically, `1::,6` is a tuple of a slice (`1::`) and a number (`6`). The slice is of the form `start:stop[:stride]`. Leaving the stride blank (`1::`) or not stating it (`1:`) is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. You're indexing by an identical `slice` object.

Answer (score 0):

It's like this:
`s[start:end:step]`.
Slice s from start to end with step *step*.

Answer (score 0):

In your case data is

```
data = ['1' '0' '3' 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris' 'male' '22' '1' '0' 'A/5 21171' '7.25' '' 'S']
```

So it is equal to

```
data = ['103Br.............7.25S']
```

In this sitation there is only single item in list so data[0::4] or data[0:4] doesn't impact any thing.

If you try this it will clear your question/answer

```
print data[0][0::4]
print data[0][0:4]
```

It works like

```
data[start:end:step]
```

So it behaves as  usual if your step size is less then data length.